# Alternative name for "closed set"

Tags: general-topology, terminology, category-theory

It is usually argued (and also joked about) that classifying sets into *open* and *closed* is a bit paradoxical, since sets can be open and closed at the same time, or neither. This can be analyzed very clearly by noting that *closed* is an antonym of *open*: it means exactly *not open* (and vice versa). Then, by saying that a set is clopen, or open and closed, we are in some way claiming that the set is open and not open, and this is a basic contradiction from a logical point of view.

While I don't dare to think that I can make an impact on the use of these terms by changing the way I myself call some sets, it would be  much easier for me to at least think of them with different names. Particularly, I've been wondering about the correctness of saying *co-open* instead of *closed*.

In the first place, it makes sense because it's more natural to see the link between declaring *$A$ is co-open* and *the complement of $A$ is open*. Also, since complementation is an involution, in some natural way we can say that a *co-co-open set*, which we may understand as a *set whose complement has an open complement*, is nothing but an open set; this, I believe, is desirable behavior for the use of the *co-* prefix.

My final worry about the correctness of using *co-open* is that the *co-* prefix is widely used in category theory, and is formalized by the notion of duality (to name but a few examples: *initial* and *coinitial*, or *terminal* and *coterminal*, *product* and *coproduct*, *limit* and *colimit*, *cone* and *cocone*). So I've been wondering whether there should be some categorical formulation of a topology so that saying *$A$ is co-open in $\mathcal{C}$* was equivalent to saying *$A$ is open in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$*, where $\mathcal{C}$ was the categorical formulation of a topology in which $A$ is a closed set. This, in order to justify the use of *co-* with duality.

However, I am aware of the existence of other terms which start with the prefix *co-* but, I believe, don't have a possible categorical formulation or which were named before they were redefined in terms of categorical notions, like *cologarithm*, *cosine*, *cosecant*, *cotangent*, *cotree*.

My question would then be: aside from the issue that every mathematician writes *closed*, could *co-open* be considered correct as a terminological alternative, based on the points I exposed, and on others I might possibly have missed? At the end, if *co-open* is correct, this will be only useful for my own pedagogical reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: reminds me of this (slightly) related youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Comment: Why not “closed” and “coclosed”? “Closed” and “closure” http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator are derived from the same word. “Open” and “interior” from different. IMHO it is better to keep words with 1 root.

Comment: The link between open and closed sets is related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28order_theory%29 and dual logical connectives.

Answer (score 2):

> This can be analyzed very clearly by noting that closed is an antonym of open: it means exactly not open (and vice versa)

This is confusing. *Closed* doesn't 'mean *not open*, it means *the complement of an open set*. So a set that is both open and closed is one which is open and for which its complement is open.

I think the terminology is good because we want a closed set to be one for which every convergent sequence in that set converges to  a limit that is also in that set. We want it to be *closed* under convergence and this can only be the case if its complement is open.

So, *closed* is a valuable word in this context. If anything, I would replace *open*. I'm just beginning with this stuff though so there might be something that I'm missing.

Comment: I meant that the literal meaning of _closed_ is _not open_, not the specific mathematical definition. I see your point with the usefulness of _closed_. Basically, a set that contains its boundary. It might be the case that in certain circumstances it could be better to think of a set as _co-open_ as I defined it, and in others to consider it _closed_, referring to different aspects of the concept according to which are more important in a given setting, and making the obvious identification. This is, after all, only about how I find convenient to think of these concepts.

Comment: @Abel, right. They're two different things and I don't see what one has to do with the other. It seems like comparing the two is just a cause for confusion. Like I said, I'm just a nobody though.

Comment: I suspect that Abel was talking about the regular dictionary definition which, in my dictionary, is "closed. adjective. not open"

Comment: @George: Exactly.

Comment: I guess I'm saying that _closed_ in the mathematical sense and _closed_ in the English sense are two _entirely_ different words that only happen to share a spelling and pronunciation. So the _literal_ meaning of _closed_ is not _not open_ but _the complement of an open set_.

Comment: @knucklebumper: I agree, but I'm arguing that some confusion stems from that particular choice of words.